# React - Arrow functions error (proposal class fields)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

These are working

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hello: this.hello()
    };

    this.hello = this.hello.bind(this);
  }

  hello() {
    return 'hello';
  }
```

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hello: this.hello()
    };
  }

  hello = () => {
    return 'hello';
  };
```

```
state = {
    hello: this.hello()
  };

  hello() {
    return 'hello';
  }
```

And this one is NOT

```
state = {
    hello: this.hello()
  };

  hello = () => {
    return 'hello;
  };
```

I don't get it. The third example can't even access 'this' (including props)
How am I supposed to use a binded function in the state when I write the state this way, and why doesn't it work?

This is the error I receive (NOT in the console, which says successful, but on the site)

TypeError: this.hello is not a function

app/src/Page.js:11
   8 |  };
   9 | 
  10 |  state = {

> 11 |    hello: this.hello()
>        | ^  12 |  };
>     13 | 
>     14 |  hello = () => {

Comment: I'm curious, what is your use case for storing the method of the same class in it's own state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When those class properties are transpiled, they get moved to the end of the constructor, *in the order that they are written*. So when you do this...

```
class Example {
  state = {
    hello: this.hello()
  }; 

  hello = () => {
    return 'hello;
  };
}
```

...it gets transpiled into roughly this:

```
class Example {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      hello: this.hello()
    };

    this.hello = () => {
      return 'hello;
    };
  }
}
```

In this transpiled code, you're trying to access this.hello before this.hello has been defined, and thus you get the error. Instead, you need to change the order, so that you define the function first, and use it after.

```
class Example {
  hello = () => {
    return 'hello;
  };

  state = {
    hello: this.hello()
  }; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, do I have to do this just in case I use a function in my state at the beginning? Because it seems that all the other times the "below" syntax is working fine.. or  I'm just dumb

Comment: You only need to do it if initializing one class field depends on another class field.